# Qt компиляция проекта с boost, undefined reference, ld returned exit 1 status

Tags: c++, qt, boost, qmake

Доброго времени суток, Собственно ошибка:

```
undefined reference to `bool invertMatrix<double>

(boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double, 
boost::numeric::ublas::basic_row_major<unsigned long, long>, 
boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<double, std::allocator<double> > > 
const&, boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double, 
boost::numeric::ublas::basic_row_major<unsigned long, long>, 
boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<double, std::allocator<double> > >&)'
```

файл "utils.h":

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/lu.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
// потом другие инклюды

using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;

template<typename T> bool   invertMatrix(const matrix<T>& input, matrix<T>& inverse);
```

файл "utils.cpp"

```
#include "utils.h"

template<typename T> bool invertMatrix(const matrix<T>& input, matrix<T>& inverse)
{
    int m = inverse.size1(), n = inverse.size2();
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            if (i == j) inverse(i, j) = 1.;
            else inverse(i, j) =0.;
        }
    }
    typedef permutation_matrix<std::size_t> pmatrix;

    // create a working copy of the input
    matrix<T> A(input);

    // create a permutation matrix for the LU-factorization
    pmatrix pm(A.size1());

    // perform LU-factorization
    int res = lu_factorize(A, pm);
    if (res != 0)
        return false;

    // create identity matrix of "inverse"
    inverse.assign(identity_matrix<T> (A.size1()));

    // backsubstitute to get the inverse
    lu_substitute(A, pm, inverse);

    return true;
}
```

использую эту функцию вызывая в файле "cluster.cpp"

```
using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
...
matrix<double>* S = covMatrix(b->m, points);
matrix<double> S_inv(S->size1(), S->size2());
if(! invertMatrix<double>((*S), S_inv)) return 0.0;
```

Наверное нужно указать флаги в .pro файле но я не знаю какие. как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас объявление шаблонной функции и её определения лежат в разных файлах. Добавьте определенние шаблонной функции в .h файл.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, можете дать источники где можно почитать о таких тонкостях? Просто у меня в том же файле объявлена другая шаблонная функция, и все работало.

Comment: другая функция не использовала типы boost

Comment: Если не страшен английский, то вот хорошо объяснено:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file
Вкратце - каждый раз, когда вы используете шаблонную функцию, компилятор подставляет вместо неё код из определения с подставленным типом T. Если вы описываете функцию в .cpp файле, то в момент использования фунции компилятор не знает, какой код он должен подставить в месте её вызова.